# hostapd failing to respond to DHCP discover nl80211: Frame command failed:

Tags: networking, wifi, driver, hostapd

I'm trying to set up a AP by using `hostapd` and I was unable to even after following the tutorial notes step by step:
After running `hostapd` with `dnsmasq` The AP gets advertised on the air, but attempting to connect one station to it , despite ackonwledging the handshake between the nodes I get the error

```
nl80211: Frame command failed: ret=-22 (Invalid argument) (freq=2432 wait=0)
```

Steps I followed

```
vim hostapd.conf
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=myhotspot
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=KeePGuessinG
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

```
vim /etc/dnsmasq.conf 
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,12h
```

```
# Setup the interface
$ ip link set wlp5s0 down
$ ip addr flush dev wlp5s0
$ ip link set wlp5s0 up
$ ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev wlan0
# start hostapd
$ sudo killall dnsmasq; dnsmasq
$ sudo hostapd
```

Then I attempt the connection from Client"A" and
`sudo systemctl status networkmanager`

```
DHCPDISCOVER on wls1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
dhcp4 request timed out
```

On the server if I do
`sudo tcpdump -nnvv -i wlan1 port 67`

```
02:45:38.207802 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 3994, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 368)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 56:27:fc:a1:04:80, length 340, xid 0x30e4e005, secs 189, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Client-Ethernet-Address 56:27:fc:a1:04:80
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether 56:27:fc:a1:04:80
            SLP-NA Option 80, length 0""
            NOAUTO Option 116, length 1: Y
            MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1472
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 44: "dhcpcd-8.1.2:Linux-5.4.79-v7+:armv7l:BCM2835"
            Hostname Option 12, length 11: "raspberrypi"
            T145 Option 145, length 1: 1
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 14:
              Subnet-Mask, Classless-Static-Route, Static-Route, Default-Gateway
              Domain-Name-Server, Hostname, Domain-Name, MTU
              BR, Lease-Time, Server-ID, RN
              RB, Option 119
nl80211: Frame command failed: ret=-22 (Invalid argument) (freq=2432 wait=0)
```

Comment: `even after following the tutorial notes` which tutorial?

Comment: thisone https://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/

Comment: last updated more than 2 years ago. I would suggest you try a more recent one first. Or maybe start off with the RPF documentation?

Comment: Ok it's solved , there were two issues on the dnsmasq service.1) The service was failing to initiate as the own initiation of `dnsmasq` created a process on top stepping on the same Ports (you just need to `sudo kill <dnsmasqPID>` and `sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq` . 2nd) I've got the IP range of `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` missconfigured  . Now they are on the same subnet so `dnsmasq.service` works accordingly. Thanks

Comment: The problem is still on , but I should re-write the question. Now I'm able to connect a station , but it doesn't last more than 3 minutes . `hostapd` suddenly bings the AP down , with the following error `nl80211: Frame command failed: ret=-22 (Invalid argument) (freq=2437 wait=0)`

Comment: Problem solved: As stated in here https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/302 `hostapd` will interfere with `network-manager` if both running at the same time , so unable `network-manager` was my solution. I wonder how I could `ssh` on the pi now without `network-manager` I believe I will be able to tell `network-manager` to not to manage `wlan1`

Comment: Please create an answer with your solution. Only accepting an answer will finish the question. Then please mark the answer as the accepted one after two days with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

So mainly I was doing three things wrong in here, so in order for you to not to have the same mistakes here I disclose them:

1st) Double check the DHCP adress range lease on `sudo vim /etc/dnsmasq.conf` to be on the same subnet than the ip that you previously assign to your AP device (when you raise the interface)
(remember than before activating `hostapd` you need to assign an ip with this line of commands):

```
sudo ip link set <devicename> down
sudo ip addr flush dev <devicename> 
sudo ip link set <devicename> up
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev <devicename>
```

For this IP you should have

```
sudo vim /etc/dnsmasq.conf
interface=<devicename>
dhcp-range=192.168.1.50,192.168.1.150,12h
```

2nd) Dont start `dnsmasq` directly as a normal process but rely on it as a daemon, so anytime you have done a change on `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` just `sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq` , if you have any problems you should check the output of this daemon on `sudo systemctl status dnsmasq`

3rd) The important step I was missing!! .  `hostapd` will have conflict with `NetworkManager` if this lastone is still managing the NIC , `hostapd` will initiate the AP but will drop the connection misteriously at 2 mins of having created it. Solution. Unmanage the NIC by `NetworkManager` , there are 2 ways of doing this:

- `nmcli`: `sudo nmcli device set ifname <devicename> managed no`
  This solution will not be persistent
- A persistant solution will be altering the `NetworkManager.conf` adding the following lines

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:<devicename>
```

Then you should restart NetworkManager daemon `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`